# PHP timezone not set

Tags: timezone, php

First of all, i don't have access to the php.ini in the webserver.

In my local server I put `date.timezone = "Europe/Lisbon"` in my php.ini.

Is it possible to change this in .htaccess? or, what is the alternative?

At the moment I get this error in web server for `phpmailer():`

```
Strict Standards:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. ....
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On second thought, ini_set may not be the best way to go. Apparently E_STRICT standards say that you should use `date_default_timezone_set` instead.

Try something like:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

$tz = date_default_timezone_get();
```

More info can be found here about the issue:
http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/739376.html

And here for the default_timezone functions:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

**Edit:** I found this little gem while I was browsing github.

```
// has to be set to reach E_STRICT compatibility, does not affect system/app settings
date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get());
```

This seems like the best solution.

Comment: I found this answer by Googling “date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get())” when I saw the GET version returns not false but “UTC”, and it occurred to me this should work to prevent errors in a timezone agnostic way. I wanted to make sure I wasn’t crazy. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Try [`ini_set`](http://www.php.net/ini_set) at the top of your script.

```
ini_set("date.timezone", "Europe/Lisbon");
```

Comment: More specifically he means: ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not difficult. You can change `date.timezone` in the `php.ini` and delete => ; <= is the comment in the `php.ini`

for example
[Date]

; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions

; http://php.net/date.timezone

date.timezone =Europe/Paris

http://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-14406518-probleme-avec-l-heure-en-php

Comment: Do you need "" ?