# PHP & jQuery datetime picker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I am using the jQuery datetime picker to take the user input .

I have dateformat like `dateFormat: "d-MM-yy",  in my jQuery setting   it returns the date like

```
15-January-2013 20:00
```

Unfortunately my php db accepting the value in `2013-01-20 20:00`
 format

I can use php `strotime()` to parse the date exactly like  `2013-01-15 20:00`   but this can causes the timezone error so i want to `2013-01-15 20:00`  as a raw string to the php side .

Is their any way so that user can see  like `15-January-2013 20:00`  in input box and my php program will get the `2013-01-15 20:00`  value .

**Update**

I want `15-January-2013 20:00`   to be `2013-01-15 20:00`   in php side

Comment: There shouldn't be a timezone issue if you're submitting a date from the client side.

Comment: You can always change the jQuery date format

Comment: If "the timezone error" is [It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208666/php-timezone-not-set), it isn't related to your issue and you'll have to fix it anyway.

Comment: @VladPreda  i can change that but for user i have to keep like that only because that is readable .

Comment: and one more intresting thing      $meeting_time =    $_POST['meeting_time'];
   
   print $meeting_time;    output = 16-January-2013 18:00+++++++++++++++++++++2013-01-16 18:01    why this one minute difference always 


  print  "+++++++++++++++++++++";

$pub = date('Y-m-d H:m', strtotime($meeting_time));

Answer (score 0):

It's what I did in php file to insert into database (MySql)

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d')
```

It's only for date, because I use time separately. If you check on php.net, wouldn't hard to figure out how to up date and time together.

Comment: By the way, I find it easy to deal with date and time in PHP and MySQL (with pre build functions) rather than Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Datepicker supports an alternate form field. This field can be hidden and you can set it up to fill it with a more php friendly date string.

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="phpDate" />
<input type="text" id="date" />
```

JavaScript

```
$( "input#date" ).datetimepicker({ altField: "#phpDate", altFormat: "yy-mm-dd", altTimeFormat:"HH:mm" });
```

See the [Datepicker altField/altFormat documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) and the [Datetimepicker options](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-options) for details.

Comment: Which has the same options (and some more). You can use it the same way I showed here.