# Right timezone for timestamp

Tags: php, time, timestamp

The code below would set open and closed on my website. But it is not in the right time zone. How do i set it to the Dutch time zone?

So can some one help me out.

And also i have a question about setting it in days.
So you can set on the website the shippingtime depending on day. So on monday the shipping time is: send today. Or on sunday it is send on monday.

```
<?php

/**
 * Based on the following business hours:
 * (Note : I setup the hours for each day if they carry-over)
 * everyday is open from 09:00 AM - 12:00 AM
 * Sun/Sat open extra from 12:00 AM - 01:00 AM
 */
$storeSchedule = [
    'Sun' => ['00:00 AM' => '00:00 AM'],
    'Mon' => ['9:00 AM' => '00:00 PM'],
    'Tue' => ['9:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'],
    'Wed' => ['9:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'],
    'Thu' => ['9:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'],
    'Fri' => ['9:00 AM' => '05:30 PM'],
    'Sat' => ['9:00 AM' => '04:30 PM']
];

// current OR user supplied UNIX timestamp
$timestamp = time();

// default status
$status = 'momenteel gesloten, stuur ons een <a href="/contacts/">mail</a>';

// get current time object
$currentTime = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($timestamp);

// loop through time ranges for current day
foreach ($storeSchedule[date('D', $timestamp)] as $startTime => $endTime) {

    // create time objects from start/end times
    $startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $startTime);
    $endTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $endTime);

    // check if current time is within a range
    if (($startTime < $currentTime) && ($currentTime < $endTime)) {
        $status = '<b>bereikbaar op: Tel: 023-5313188</b> of <a href="/contacts/"><b>mail</b></a>';
        break;
    }
}

echo "Onze klantenservice is $status";
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP timezone not set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208666/php-timezone-not-set)

Answer (score 0):

use this for instantiating the current DateTime Object in Dutch Timezone:

```
$current = new DateTime(
    'now',
    new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam')
);
```

---

the problem was at the DateTime comparison. Creating a DateTime object from only the time sets the date to 1970-01-01...

```
/**
 * Based on the following business hours:
 * (Note : I setup the hours for each day if they carry-over)
 * everyday is open from 09:00 AM - 12:00 AM
 * Sun/Sat open extra from 12:00 AM - 01:00 AM
 */
$storeSchedule = [
    'Sun' => ['00:00 AM' => '00:00 AM'],
    'Mon' => ['9:00 AM' => '00:00 PM'],
    'Tue' => ['9:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'],
    'Wed' => ['9:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'],
    'Thu' => ['9:00 AM' => '05:00 PM'],
    'Fri' => ['9:00 AM' => '05:30 PM'],
    'Sat' => ['9:00 AM' => '04:30 PM']
];

// current OR user supplied UNIX timestamp
$timestamp = '2015-03-12 12:00:00'; // shows it is open
//$timestamp = '2015-03-12 8:59:59'; // shows closed
//$timestamp = '2015-03-12 9:00:00'; // shows open
//$timestamp = 'now'; // shows current status

// default status
$status = 'momenteel gesloten, stuur ons een <a href="/contacts/">mail</a>';

// default timezone
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam');

// get current time object
$currentTime = new DateTime($timestamp, $timeZone);

// loop through time ranges for current day

foreach ($storeSchedule[date('D', $timestamp)] as $startTime => $endTime) {

    // create time objects from start/end times
    $startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat(
        'Y-m-d h:i A',
        $currentTime->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $startTime,
        $timeZone
    );
    $endTime = DateTime::createFromFormat(
        'Y-m-d h:i A',
        $currentTime->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $endTime,
        $timeZone
    );

    // check if current time is within a range
    if (($startTime <= $currentTime) && ($currentTime <= $endTime)) {
        $status = '<b>bereikbaar op: Tel: 023-5313188</b> of <a href="/contacts/"><b>mail</b></a>';
        break;
    }
}

echo "Onze klantenservice is $status";
```

Comment: Thanks, but where do i put that code or what do i have to replace. I tried this:

`// get current time object
$currentTime = (new DateTime(
    'now',
    new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam')))->setTimestamp($timestamp);`

But no luck and still same problem.

Comment: you don't need to use `setTimestamp()`.

Comment: [saved too early] ... when instantiating DateTime, the first parameter of the constructor could be the `$timestamp` variable. I was using 'now', because it exactly does what it sounds like. In your code example above, `$timestamp = time()` sets the current timestamp with the timezone set on the server. that's exactly what the 'now' parameter does, but the second parameter tells the DateTime object the timezone to use. instead of 'now', all kind of strings can be used, e.g. '2000-01-01 00:00:01'. but please, consult the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: oh, and don't forget to set the DateTimeZone for the `DateTime::createFromFormat()` method too. it's the third parameter...

Comment: Thanks

I have got it for this:
`$currentTime = new DateTime('2015-01-01 00:00:01', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));`

But i don't understand how to change this: 
`// create time objects from start/end times
    $startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $startTime);
    $endTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $endTime);`

Comment: as documented: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php, `$endTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $endTime, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam');`.

Comment: Thanks and tested it but no luck.

Comment: took a look at the code itself. it's not the timezones... you're creating the DateTime Objects from the hours only. so in fact your comparison looks like this: `1970-01-01 10:00AM < 2015-01-01 11:00 && 2015-01-01 11:00AM < 1970-01-01 05:00PM`. working on a solution....

Comment: Ah ok, i see. A better code for openingtimes (in real time) is what i'm looking for. So maybe the code is have is wrong.