# PHP echo Date from HTML Form and format it from Y-m-d to d-m-Y error 31-12-1969

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, date

I have a text link to pass a date GET in format Y-m-d because is comming from MySQL like that.
The page receiving this GET uses the follow code to echo the date I got from previous page

the link is like this

```
page.php?thedate=2015-06-30
```

The page I need to show this date must convert this date like this

```
<?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($_GET["thedate"]));?>
```

so we show 30-06-2015

But it show with this code

```
31-12-1969
```

What can the problem be?

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce the error, I get `30-06-2015` are you doing anything to `thedate` before you try and echo it out anywhere?

Comment: nothing, that is why it is strange

Comment: Try `<?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime(urldecode($_GET["thedate"])));?>`

Comment: `thedate`'s value is definitely not '2015-06-30'. The value you are trying to convert to time is invalid, thus it's rendering 01-01-1970 minus some hours due to your timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is looking OK. But few thoughts, what could go wrong:

**At first:** Try the following code:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_GET['thedate']); // check what it is?
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw'); // set default timezone to your zone / user zone
    echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime('2015-06-30')); // check that date is working with plain text
?>
```

At first remember to always use `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');`. It can be really important for Your application. Second, enter the date in plain text mode. If this works, it mean that the date function is working ok, and there is something wrong with Your GET or after GET variable manipulation.

**Second:** *NEVER, EVER DON'T VALIDATE _GET VARIABLES.* Sorry for double negation, but maybe becouse of that, it can be more memorable ;).
**Always parse the data that user enters in the URL**. Always parse:

- _GET data
- _POST data
- _REQUEST data
- _SERVER data (yes, some of them can be manipulated
- all other vulnerable data...

So summing up: Your code (the one You entered is OK), check the GET variable and the after get variable manipulation. And always check all the data that is not trusted.

---

More on validating data:

- filter_var: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php
- preg_match: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
- htmlspecialchar: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

---

According to one of the comments solution with using urldecode on _GET variable:

```
<?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime(urldecode($_GET["thedate"])));?>
```

**"Warning! The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results."**

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: IMHO setting default timezone in server's configuration is much better option than to declare it in every php file.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For the 100% safety solution, we can put: date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get()); somewhere in the beginning of index.php or configuration class. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208666/php-timezone-not-set